# c# removing users from security tab

Tags: c#

I am removing removing permissions from a folder to given users i want to be able to remove the user from the folder security tab list

excerpt code

```
myDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Write | FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
     PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));

                myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

i want to remove the user after permission is remove..

[picture http://i93.photobucket.com/albums/l66/reavenm/Capture_zps51403cae.png](http://i93.photobucket.com/albums/l66/reavenm/Capture_zps51403cae.png)

i tried to add that to my code here

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(); 
string sql = "SELECT key, fdate, user, perm, sfolder FROM  permuser WHERE        fdate=CURDATE()";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
MySqlCommand cmdSel = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdSel).Fill(dataSet, "permuser");


foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["permuser"].Rows)
    {
         string fuser = row["user"].ToString();
         string pathtxt = row["sfolder"].ToString();

        DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathtxt);
        DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
        string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + fuser;


                myDirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Write | FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
     PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));

                myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
                   //it should go here
    }

connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
}


catch (MySqlException ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: If you don't have to do it in C#, there is a command line utility you can use.  Google "icacls" (or "cacls" for older versions of windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following to remove users/groups from folders they no longer have access to.

```
var accountToRemove = "Some account";
var security = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
var rules = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
{
    if (rule.IdentityReference.Value == accountToRemove) 
        security.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(rule);

}
```

Replace your foreach loop with the following

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["permuser"].Rows)
{
     string fuser = row["user"].ToString();
     string pathtxt = row["sfolder"].ToString();

    DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathtxt);
    DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
    string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + fuser;

    var rules = myDirectorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
    foreach( var rule in rules)
    {
        if (rule.IdentityReference.Value == User) 
            security.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(rule);

    }
}
```

Comment: this will not remove the user form active directory ?, just from the specified folder ?

Comment: i tried to add that to my code with no avail, obviously replacing the variables.

Comment: I would recommend printing out what the file system thinks the existing users are. Then you can make your inputs match what it is expecting.

foreach (var rule in rules) Log.InfoFormat("User: {0}", rule.IdentityReference.Value)

Comment: User = domain\user and fuser = user                                  since I already have a for each i modified the code and adapt it i end using 2 lines but dont work

Comment: is the code in your original post how you implemented what i posted? If it is, it will not work. You have to get the actual list of rules on the DirectorySecurity object and remove one of them. You can't just do RemoveAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(...))

Comment: Case of the data in the database may be different from the file system. Are the cases on the data in your database matching what the ACLs are saying?